# What does "2.5× what you're on" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, british-english

Given this context:

> "Would love to offer you the job. At least 2.5× what you're on."

What does "what you're on" mean in this sentence? The person's current wage?

Comment: I've replaced the "X" in your post with the multiplication symbol (×) instead. Am I correct in assuming you're not confused about that aspect of the phrase, and that the multiplication symbol is what you meant to you use?

Comment: *2.5X* ... is two and a half multiplied by some mystery number. *x2.5* ... is two and a half times, or times two point five. Put the 'sign' in front, otherwise it's a variable in a mathematical expression. - But now someone edited it with an actual multiplication sign, which no one ever uses. Whatever you do, don't use uppercase X unless you want them to pronounce it as *ecks*.

Answer (score 35):

Certainly in a British English setting, and in this context (employment/salary/payment for work done), "what you are on" means "your current salary, or annual, monthly, daily, hourly (etc) pay rate".

The 'X' in '2.5 X' should be read as 'times' and in mathematical material will be the multiplication sign **×** which is not identical with the letter X or x in the alphabet.

> Let's talk about payment. What are you on at your job?
>
> I'm on £30,000 per year.
>
> We'd like to offer you a salary of 2.5 times what you're on -
> £75,000 per year.
>
> I'm on £20 per hour.
>
> We'd like to offer you 2.5 times what you're on - £50 per hour.

Comment: This must be a BrE usage.  In AmE, being *on something* will get you fired.

Comment: @EllieK - In the UK, we have that other usage too,  being 'on' some kind of intoxicant or drug, e.g. Joe Smith says the project will be finished in March. What is he on? This might be OK informally, but in any kind of message on record, I'd say 'I suggest that Joe Smith may wish to reconsider his estimate of the completion timescale' to avoid censure for being disrespectful. Of course really being intoxicated in the workplace is usually grounds for immediate dismissal. As always, context is important.

Comment: @EllieK - in fact, in BrE we can use 'on', in a work context, to discuss being involved in some kind of arrangement, scheme, process, programme ('program'), etc. I am on a fixed-term contract, I am on night shifts, I am on performance management, I am on a warning, I am on overtime after 5 PM, etc. 'On' is a very versatile preposition.

Comment: I'd add that it's not necessarily a salary.  It could be an hourly rate, eg _"I'm on $20 per hour"_ or some other kind of provision, eg _"I'm on time and a half right now because it's Saturday"_

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the 'X' would always be pronounced as 'times', not like the letter X. (It's in brackets in your example but an unfamiliar reader might assume it was just for clarification.)

Comment: Great answer. In AmE, we’d probably say, “Two and a half times what you’re making.”

Comment: I'm not sure if I've heard this before, but as an AmE speaker it made intuitive sense.

Comment: @Davislor - yes. Here in the UK, also, 'two and a half times' would be more natural, especially in speech, than '2.5 times'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey All of those examples you list there are commonly used in AmE, too, though “on probation” would be much more likely than “on a warning.” Dawood’s “on time and a half” is also common in AmE. But “on {pay rate}” for whatever reason is not—as others have said, I had no trouble understanding it in context, but I’ve never personally seen it before. “2.5× what you make,” “2.5× what you get,” etc. would be common AmE phrasings, but “2.5× what you’re on” is unheard of here.

Comment: AmE here. Made sense to me. 2.5x what you're *at* might be slightly more american?

Comment: @KRyan - in the UK most people starting with a new employer have to work a 'probation period' typically three or six months, during which they can be terminated without notice, or short notice such as one week for e.g. poor performance, incapacity, minor misconduct, bad timekeeping or attendance, etc. Sometimes in mild cases the period is extended. Such a person would be unlikely to say 'I am on probation' because that expression is used for people who have sentenced by a court to a punishment where they report to a 'probation officer' regularly for a period, rather than go to jail.

Comment: @KRyan - A person might say 'I am on my probation period' though. I once saw a case where two people were caught falsifying their time sheets. The one on her probation period was terminated immediately, while the one who had been employed for years was given a final warning lasting one year (even minor misconduct in that time - out!). They should have known better, and their guilt was all the greater because they had encouraged the probationer to commit the fraud.

Comment: Note that in AmE in the tech industry, pronouncing 'X' as the letter X in this context is increasingly common—eg "we'll have 5X the budget", or "we need to 10X the output". See on ELU: [How do people in Silicon Valley pronounce "10x" as in a "10x engineer"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/452303/59654)

Comment: Yuck. Can we make that not a thing? It makes me think of Sean Murry from No Man's Sky. *It's going to have ten ecks the planets and a quadrillion ecks the possibilities* and if you complain hard enough about no multiplayer, eventually there will be more than one ecks people playing together.

Comment: @MiloP - we don't do the X thing so much in the UK but I do hear K (said as 'kay') a lot for thousands in a money context (He's on fifty kay, his Tesla cost 75 kay, etc).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Despite America’s insistence on metric avoidance, we use “k” for “thousand” quite commonly also.